Why does Prov 30:33 say that milk is churned to make butter?
We read in Proverbs 30:33(KJV):

Surely the churning of milk bringeth forth butter, and the wringing of the nose bringeth forth blood: so the forcing of wrath bringeth forth strife.

Traditionally, milk is  made sour with the help of bacteria and the product is called curd or yoghurt. By churning of the curd or yoghurt, you get butter. Of course, milk could be boiled , thickened and cooled in order to produce cream, which in turn could  be churned to make butter. But that is a cumbersome process.It is not clear if some ancient technique facilitated extraction of butter direct from milk . Or, it it possible that ancient people used the same  word for milk, curd, yoghurt and cream ? My question is : Why does Prov 30:33 say that milk is churned to get butter ?

Your first sentence is not true - butter is made by simply churning fresh milk.  Adding renit or acid to milk produces cheese whose remnant is curd.

Thanks, Dottard. Lactobacillus bacteria are used in formation of curd. Milk can also be split by lemon or acid to make cottage cheese which is allowed to rest in the open air and transform into commercial cheese over a period of time.

@Dottard — Isn't English wonderful. You are both using the word "curd" to refer to two very different things. See my comment on Jason_'s answer.

"milk could be boiled , thickened and cooled in order to produce cream" — that would be like "evaporated milk", milk with half the water removed, not cream.

It says that because it's true that that's how butter is made.
You might watch: Churning in the Olden Days -- Irish Butter Making

Churning is the process of shaking up cream or whole milk to make
butter, usually using a device called butter churn. In Europe from the
Middle Ages until the Industrial Revolution, a churn was usually as
simple as a barrel with a plunger in it, moved by hand. These have
mostly been replaced by mechanical churns. (Wikipedia)


A 3 step process is given by Wikipedia:


Churning physically agitates the cream until it ruptures the fragile    membranes surrounding the milk fat. Once broken, the fat
droplets can    join with each other and form clumps of fat.
As churning continues, larger clusters of fat collect until they
begin to form a network with the air bubbles that are generated by
the churning; this traps the liquid and produces foam. As the fat
clumps increase in size, there are also fewer to enclose the air
cells. So the bubbles pop, run together, and the foam begins to
leak. This leakage is called buttermilk.
The cream separates into butter and buttermilk. The buttermilk is
drained off, and the remaining butter is kneaded to form a network
of fat crystals that becomes the continuous phase, or dispersion
medium, of a water-in-fat emulsion. Working the butter also creates
its desired smoothness. Eventually, the water droplets become so
finely dispersed in the fat that butter’s texture seems dry. Then it
is frozen into cubes, then melted, then frozen again into bigger
chunks to sell.


The point in the scripture though is more about the process of agitation (churning) leading to a result (butter). He uses a relatable metaphor to make it easier to grasp the idea that actions lead to consequences. Every cause has an effect.
Milk churned (cause) → Butter (effect)
Wringing of the nose (cause) → Blood (effect)
Forcing of wrath (cause) → Strife (effect)

Thanks, Jason-. The video starts with saying that milk is kept in room temperature until it becomes thick and sour. The sour milk is what we call  'curd ' in the Orient. Buttermilk is what remains after the curd is churned and butter removed.

In tropical countries, the shelf life of milk in room temperature  is low say a day if boiled and cooled. When milk is cultured into curd , it has more shelf life in room temperature, only that it turns more sour over a period of time.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan says "what we call 'curd ' in the Orient" — it can be very confusing sometimes. To make dahi (yogurt), you first heat the milk to denature its protein to prevent the formation of what Occidentals call "curd" (as in curds and whey, or cheese). Two very different milk products, but each can be called curd. ¶ Lesson: always check where a recipe originates before making it (I was once tricked by a recipe that called for "cornflour" and disastrously discovered that the British use "cornflour" for what is really cornstarch, and say "super-fine cornmeal" for cornflour.)

Thanks, Ray Butterworth. In Indian markets you get two different products by the names Dahi ( curd) and Yoghurt. Strains of bacteria used in the products are different.


By churning of the curd or yoghurt, you get butter.
… milk could be boiled, thickened and cooled in order to produce cream

Neither of these are true.
Real milk (straight from the cow, not the industrially prepared product that we today buy from the supermarket) naturally separates itself into cream and skim milk.
One simply skims the cream off the top, puts it into an appropriate container, and churns it until the fat (butter) separates from the buttermilk.
Until the 1920s, when homogenized milk was invented, all milk was like that.
People used to shake up the bottle before pouring it.
Or they poured off some or all of the layer of cream and used it as coffee cream or whipped cream, or for producing home-made butter.
Try it yourself: buy a container of real whipping cream, shake it for a while, and you'll find lumps of butter floating in it.

Thanks, Ray Butterworth . Milk must have been thicker and creamier in Biblical times. After all, human beings started digesting cow milk just a few thousand years back . A cow generally has only a calf at a time. By nature, a cow's  milk is intended for the sole calf and the produced to that limit. It is the human intervention and domestication that caused cows produce more but thinner milk , right ?

@KadalikattJosephSibichan, Changes in Canadians' preferences for milk and dairy products says "The quantity of milk produced by each cow has gone up almost 400% since 1921".

Thanks, Ray Butterworth, for the additional information.
